# Question regarding the number of zeros of Dirichlet L-function

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, dirichlet-series, l-functions

I have encountered the following result: Let $T\geq 2$, and let $N^*(\alpha, q, T)$ denote the number of zeros of all the L-functions $L(s, \chi)$ with primitive characters $\chi$ modulo $q$ in the region $\text{Re }s \geq \alpha$ and $|\text{Im }s| \leq T$. Then
$$
N^*(\alpha, q, T) \ll (qT)^{12(1 - \alpha)/5} \log^{B}(qT)
$$
for some absolute constant $B>0$.

1. Could someone please provide a reference for this result? I have looked into Davenport (Multiplicative Number Theory) or Kolwaski-Iwaniec but I couldn't find it... (They have the result for $0 < \text{Re }s < 1$ but not in the above form)
2. Does the result hold for imprimitive characters as well?

Thank you very much.

Comment: See [Titchmarsh](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Titchmarsh_TheTheoryoftheRiemannZeta-Function.pdf)'s book p.121 for the proof for $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: The proof for a generic $L$-function is essentially the same as for the Riemann zeta function. The $q$ terms come from the conductor of the functional equation. The problem with imprimitive $L$-functions is with the conductor in the functional equation. For example, if $\chi$ is the primitive Dirichlet character mod $2$, then $L(s, \chi^2)$ is really the zeta function missing its two factor. Is the true "conductor" of $\chi^2$ really $1$? Even worse, $L(s, \chi^2)$ violates the corresponding Riemann hypothesis, as $L(1, \chi^2) = 0$. The proof is the same, but details need to be changed.

Comment: @mixedmath Thank you for your comment! I just wanted to verify. Does it mean that if I define $N(\alpha, q,T)$ to be with respect to all characters $\chi$ modulo $q$ (instead of just primitive ones), then $N(\alpha, q, T)$ satisfy the same upper bound as above?

Comment: @JohnnyT. You define it for a single primitive character. Obviously the bound extends to finitely many primitive characters. See the proof for $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: I was interested in seeing more details for the imprimitive ones.